# Get a point's position from an angle and the length of the line

Tags: python, pygame, position, line, angle

I'm programming a game in Python, with pygame, and I'd like to make a function that draws a line in a specific direction from a point, with a specific length, for example, the definition of the funcion would be: `def draw_line(position1: (int, int), angle: int, line_length: int, line_width: float, color: Color):`

What can I do for calculating the second point to draw the line?

I have a little schematic of the problem, I want to get position2, to draw the line with pygame.

[image]

Comment: This is just geometry bub. Python has a `math` module.

Comment: @SuperStew Can you extend a little more please, I'm a starter with Python

Comment: Try asking on https://math.stackexchange.com. You definitely need to learn some trigonometry before asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a math problem, but ok, the x and y coordinate of point 2 are:

```
(x2,y2) = (x1 + line_length*cos(angle),y1 + line_length*sin(angle))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a vector. The `pygame.math.Vector2` class has a [`from_polar`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.from_polar) method to which you can pass the length and angle of the desired vector. Then add this vector to the first point and you have the second point.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


def draw_line(position, angle, line_length, line_width, color, screen):
    vector = Vector2()  # A zero vector.
    vector.from_polar((line_length, angle))  # Set the desired length and angle of the vector.
    # Add the vector to the `position` to get the second point.
    pg.draw.line(screen, color, position, position+vector, line_width)


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray13')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    draw_line((100, 200), 30, 120, 2, BLUE, screen)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Very good answer, as always. No need to reinvent the wheel when your library offers you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that ViG's answer works the same in 3D; you just have to do the same equation, with the z axis resulting in the same formula as the x axis:

```py
from math import cos, sin

def getPointInDir(x0, y0, z0, angX, angY, angZ, distance):
    x1 = x0 + distance*cos(angX)
    y1 = y0 + distance*sin(angY)
    z1 = z0 + distance*cos(angZ)
    
    result = [x1, y1, z1]
    return result
```

You don't even have to use vectors!